# Array with elements has length = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am making an application on javascript, the problem is that I have an object containing an array with elements, but when I try to get one of them it behaves as if the array was empty.

The way I am populating my array is very simple:

```
object.array = new Array();
for(element in resultFromDatabase){
    object.array.push(element);
}
console.debug(object);
console.debug(object['array']);
```

I made a console.debug() of the object and in the next line a console.debug() of the array within the object.

The first one shows the elements of the object including the array I need, with three elements inside of it.
The second one shows an empty array.

Do you have any idea what could this be?

Comment: Any more information? What is resultFromDatabase? http://jsfiddle.net/3YaPN/

Comment: Would it be possible to have a picture of the console with the logs ? Is the code really like this ?

Comment: Can you show us the output of the `console.debug(object)` results?

Comment: Maybe your resulteFromDatabase is empty.

Comment: works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/kvACS/

Comment: I can't upload images because I have just created my account here :(.

Comment: The result from database is an array of strings. 
It is not empty because the first console.debug shows the elements within the Array, it is when I directly try to access any of them when it appears to be empty.

Comment: Upload your image to imgur and give us the link

Comment: What browser are u using?

Comment: try: `console.log(JSON.stringify(object,null,2))` and paste the results here

Comment: this is the result from the console.debug over the whole object:
http://imgur.com/mQJ6bZS
this is the result from both console.debug:
http://imgur.com/cANMq3x

The array I want to use is 'imagenes'.

Comment: OK, here are a few basic debugging questions: 1) Does @KevinB's jsfiddle link work correctly for you? 2) If so, is your above code EXACTLY what you are testing or is there more/less that you are not showing us?  3) Are you sure there is no other operation between the two console statements you are using? 4) What exactly does the console statements output (paste it here).

Comment: The important words are probably "EXACTLY" and "exactly".

Comment: There is no other operation between both console.debug().
This code is not exactly the one I have, but it is basically what it does. What I don't understand is why if there is no other operation between both console.debug, one shows one result and the other shows a different one over the same array

Comment: You still haven't answered the question about Kevin B's jsfiddle... Is that one working for you?

Comment: Yes, that code worked for me

Comment: I found a way to make it work. I still don't understand why, but if I call this function again, it works ok.

Comment: I still have this problem the first time I call it, but I suppose I'll have to call it twice.
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, but I'm going to make an assumption.

```
for (element in resultFromDatabase) {
}
```

"element" in the above example is the actual enumerator (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc). It won't contain any objects from resultFromDatabase.

The expected result from your example is an array looking something like...

```
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```